# Why is ethernet payload less than wifi payload

Tags: ethernet, wifi

Why is ethernet payload (which is 1500 bytes) less than 802.11 payload (which is 2272 bytes)? Given Ethenet has a more reliable medium.

Comment: You mean [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)? (Also consider adding practical background to your question, generally historical research is not  exactly on-topic for SO).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm studying electrical engineer and learning about layers of internet. When I reached Network Layer, the payload or the MTU as you said, according to the book, the MTU is less than 802.11. Hence, I was just curious why so

Answer (score 0):

Probably historical reasons, ethernet was used with slow dial-up modems a 1500 bytes will occupy for about 1 second a 14.4kbps ethernet line.

When 802.11 was first introduced minimum speed was 1Mbps (over 70 times faster than 14.4kbps) hence larger MTU can be used without hogging the network.

Not sure where you got your numbers from, WiFi MTU can be larger (7981)